# android object oriented programming

Tags: java, android, oop

I am fooling around with some basic programming in Android using Eclipse. I'm currently looking through a book and playing with some sample code that is written in the book.

I have noticed that in this particular book, all of the examples so far take pace in Main-Activity. I don't believe this to be very good Object Oriented programming practice as I am from a traditional Java background.

Is this the common practice for mobile platforms?  Shouldn't classes all be contained in their own files?

Comment: Can you post some examples to better illustrate your question?

Comment: OOP is not always the best practice; and splitting into thousand files does not always produce a good OOP program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Shouldn't classes all be contained in their own files?

Not necessarily as an Android `Activity` is a 'special case' class. If you haven't done already, I'd recommend you read [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) and in particular the section on 'Activities' under [Application components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#Components)...

> An activity represents a single screen with a user interface. For example, an email application might have one activity that shows a list of new emails, another activity to compose an email, and another activity for reading emails. **Although the activities work together to form a cohesive user experience in the email application, each one is independent of the others. As such, a different application can start any one of these activities (if the email application allows it).** For example, a camera application can start the activity in the email application that composes new mail, in order for the user to share a picture.

Note the section of text that I've highlighted in bold. The point is that an `Activity` in itself is not the complete app and if allowed, any third-party app can potentially invoke an `Activity` in one of your apps. As such, it is common to make an `Activity` as self-contained as possible. One particular example is the use of something like an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which provides methods to execute a background thread as well as manipulate the UI - nesting a private class which extends `AsyncTask` is quite common and simplifies code. Nesting classes which extend [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) is also common for the same reason.

That said, there is nothing wrong with using separate Java class files for POJO helper classes, for example, it just comes down to how complex your app is but it can mean taking special consideration of how certain Android classes work - the `AsyncTask` class being one in particular if defined in a separate class file, try it and you'll see what I mean. :-)

Comment: The fact that Activity is almost an app by itself should imply completely opposite than it being entirely contained in a large class. Any application is more or less "self-contained", this doesn't mean all the code should be in a single class. As you've quoted, *"activities work together to form a cohesive user experience in (an) application"*, it is actually expected that parts of UI and functionality are shared between Activities.

Comment: @Groo: "The fact that Activity is almost an app by itself..." - no this is exactly what many people new to Android believe, i.e., they think `Activity` is synonymous with 'app'. In reality, an app can have dozens of components (Activities, Services, BroadcastReceivers, Content Providers). I'm not suggesting that all Activities should contain everything - my point is that Activities are often very simple single 'page' UIs that perform a very simple action and, as such, can often contain everything they need. If there's a need for shared code then helper classes can be used.

Comment: +1 Ok, I guess I read the post too superficially, now I get it: you referred to a "self-contained" `Activity` as a part of a complete application. It is true that you don't need to split every part of your app into several files (or classes), but when doing TDD programming, it is often nice to be able to test each smallest component separately, so I tend to go in that direction most of the time. But then again, TDD is no silver bullet either. And I do use private classes to decompose complex parts of a class' functionality, and then refactor them when (and if) needed.

Answer (score 5):

OO is about putting functionality in classes. The way you write those classes defines if it is good OO or not (although this is debatable). Whether all these classes are in a single or a few files, or each class has its own file, is a matter of taste and is not directly an OO issue.

Since this is a book with (I think) small samples, it may be just as easy to read the way it is, than when all classes are in separate files.

Answer (score 0):

If you use proper OOP you can create Template based apps much more quickly & efficiently.

You should strive to do this for example if you have a generic database app and multiple databases can be used with minor changes.