# How should I create and use an object for Android?

Tags: java, android, object

I am going to be accessing an array of objects, that are saved to internal storage, throughout the Android Application. It will have things like nameString, any song chosen from the device, array of videos, and date of project.

I come from developing iPhone and iPad apps. Usually I would create an NSObject, but according to: [android object oriented programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374871/android-object-oriented-programming)  I should load this into each individual activity?

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific about what you are trying to do. There are already tons of questions about passing data between application components and storing data on the device. If you can'f ind what you're looking for after a search, ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you don't use a simple [SQL Database](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html). Each row would have the information for one Object.
Just one possibility but I would think about it.